# Hide Default Image (Icon) in Dialog

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, openfiledialog

Not so much of an issue, but more of a hassle to me. I am wanting to hide the default application icon in a `OpenFileDialog`; the icon that appears in the top left of the window. I know it's the default icon for the solution, but I don't want it there. Is there anyway of over-riding this and no I don't want to write my own dialog just to do this. There are no properties of course to alter this in any way, not sure why there isn't. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
MrCodexer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now way to do this without writing your own dialogue, apart from if you were prepared to remove the icon from the form itself. If you do not mind doing this, then remove the icon from the form by setting this value in the form properties:

```
ShowIcon: False
```

This will mean no icon will be show in your OpenFileDialogue as well as the form.

Hope this helps :)